# How to make correct wget request?

Tags: wget

I need to copy xml file from server to my folder and name it as daily.xml. Here is my code.

The problem is that every new file has name daily.xml.1, daily.xml.2 etc

How to name new file as daily.xml, and previous file as previous-daily.xml? As I know I need to use `-O` but I don't understand how to use it

```
wget -P /home/name/name2/docs/xml/ http://www.domain.com/XML/daily.xml
```

How to make correct request?

Comment: What do you like as a result? How should each file be named?

Comment: I guess "previous-previous-previous-previous-previous-...-previous-daily.xml" would be, somehow, sub-optimal?

Comment: @GyroGearloose idealy I'd like to have in this folder /home/name/name2/docs/xml/ two files: daily.xml and previous-daily.xml

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
wget -P /home/name/name2/docs/xml/  http://www.domain.com/XML/daily.xml -O daily$(date +'%Y%m%d%H%M%S').xml
```

Maybe the resolution by seconds is not fine enough and you need to have a count variable.

This dose not, however, rename your previous files.

In case your only original problem was the your system does not recognize *.xml.7 as xml-file, the command above should fix this.

Edit: as for your comment, you could do

```
mv daily.xml previous-daily.xml;wget -P /home/name/name2/docs/xml/  http://www.domain.com/XML/daily.xml -O daily.xml
```

Comment: Thanks. What if I need to have the last file named daily.xml? And that's al